# NullReferenceException retrieving value from known Request.Form[key] elements in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, request

I am trying to retrieve the values from a number of RadioButtonGroups on PostBack using the Request.Form keys like so:

```
string val = Request.Form["ControlName" + i].ToString();
```

But I keep getting a NullReferenceException.

I know the keys are a part of the collection, and if I replace the above code with:

```
Response.Write(Request.Form["RadioGroup" + i].ToString())
```

The value is displayed on the page.

Why does it throw a NullReferenceException if I try to assign it to a variable, but not when I write it to the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the second one works is probably because you changed the string from `"ControlName"` to `"RadioGroup"`.

In order to avoid the `NullReferenceException` you should avoid calling `ToString`. The [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx) already returns a `string` so the call to `ToString` is unnecessary.